# using control arrays

Tags: vb.net, textbox

i am having trouble with .net again.  i have a series of 10 text boxes.  I want to be able to populate them from an array and read there values into another array.  In vb6 I would create a text box array with 10 text boxes / indices.  I could then populate them by txtbox(i).text = arrVal(i) and to reference them arrVal(i) = txtbox(i).  I am stumped I can create 10 text boxes on a form if I have to, but I want them somehow tied to each other as they were in vb6.  Any help in how I could do this would be most appreciated

Comment: You have 4 previously unanswered questions - you need to fix that. Your question is also very vague - when you create a textbox you get a variable back. Use it to access it later. Not that hard.

Answer (score 3):

Control arrays as available in VB6 are not supported in VB.NET.  Not an issue, just create the array yourself:

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Boxes = New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
    End Sub

    Private Boxes() As TextBox

End Class
```